# Clustering (k-means, or otherwise) with a minimum cluster size constraint

Tags: r, clustering

I need to cluster units into $k$ clusters to minimize within-group sum of squares (WSS), but I need to ensure that the clusters each contain at least $m$ units.  Any idea if any of R's clustering functions allow for clustering into $k$ clusters subject to a minimum cluster size constraint?  kmeans() does not seem to offer a size constraint option.

Answer (score 6):

Use EM Clustering

In EM clustering, the algorithm iteratively refines an initial cluster model to fit the data and determines the probability that a data point exists in a cluster. The algorithm ends the process when the probabilistic model fits the data. The function used to determine the fit is the log-likelihood of the data given the model.

If empty clusters are generated during the process, or if the membership of one or more of the clusters falls below a given threshold, the clusters with low populations are reseeded at new points and the EM algorithm is rerun.

Comment: Thanks, Marianna.  I would prefer a solution that relies less heavily on (typically, unjustifiable) parametric models, but will definitely look into it.

Comment: Can this be done with K-means also? If after several iterations, too few points are assigned to a centroid, just randomly generate a new centroid?

Answer (score 6):

This problem is addressed in this paper:

Bradley, P. S., K. P. Bennett, and Ayhan Demiriz. "Constrained k-means clustering." *Microsoft Research, Redmond (2000)*: 1-8.

I have an [implementation](https://github.com/Behrouz-Babaki/MinSizeKmeans) of the algorithm in python.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!  I used the `rPython` package in R to create an interface to this implementation that I accessed from my R script.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge do you have an example somewhere (github?) on the interface you wrote to call that python package form R? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I looked around my old code but couldn't find it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would just be a matter of running the k means as part of an if loop with a test for cluster sizes, I.e. Count n in cluster k - also remember that k means will give different results for each run on the same data so you should probably be running it as part of a loop anyway to extract the "best" result

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I see a problem with this though: what if over the loops the solutions generated never satisfy the constraint? That could happen if k means were set to run with no cluster size constraint.  I'd love a solution that avoids this. (The nature of the application is such that I really need to ensure clusters are of a minimum size.)

Answer (score 2):

How large is your data set? Maybe you could try to run a hierarchical clustering and then decide which clusters retain based on your dendrogram.

If your data set is huge, you could also combine both clustering methods: an initial non-hierarchical clustering and then a hierarchical clustering using the groups from the non-hierarchical analysis. You can find an example of this approach in [Martínez-Pastor et al (2005)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15385419)

Comment: Thanks, Manuel.  This actually sounds like a very intriguing possibility.  I need to think about whether the hierarchical partitioning would impose certain constraints that would prevent the algorithm from achieving the optimal cluster partitioning directly under the size constraint.   But intuitively, I can see that this might work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by modifying the cluster assignment step (E in EM) by formulating it as a Minimum Cost Flow (MCF) linear network optimisation problem.

I have written a [python package](https://github.com/joshlk/k-mean-constrained) which uses Google's Operations Research tools's SimpleMinCostFlow which is a fast C++ implementation. Its has a standard scikit-lean API.